# object reference not set to an instance of an object console.readline.tolower

Tags: c#

I am having the hardest time trying to fix this code. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Before I start debugging, there are no red underlines or anything. But when I hit debug, this line of code `hitOrStay = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().;` gets the following error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here is my source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace finalBlackjack
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static string[] playerCards = new string[12];
    static string hitOrStay = "";
    static int total = 0, count = 1, dealerTotal = 0;
    static Random cardRandomizer = new Random();

    static void Start()
    {
        dealerTotal = cardRandomizer.Next(15, 22);
        playerCards[0] = Deal();
        playerCards[1] = Deal();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Blackjack! You were dealed " + playerCards[0] + " and " + playerCards[1] + ". \nYour total is " + total + ".\nWould you like to hit or stay?");
            hitOrStay = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        } while (!hitOrStay.Equals("hit") && !hitOrStay.Equals("stay"));
        Game();
    }

    static void Game()
    {
        if (hitOrStay.Equals("hit"))
        {
            Hit();
        }
        else if (hitOrStay.Equals("stay"))
        {
            if (total > dealerTotal && total <= 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCongrats! You won the game! The dealer's total was " + dealerTotal + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
                PlayAgain();
            }
            else if (total < dealerTotal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, you lost! The dealer's total was " + dealerTotal + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
                PlayAgain();
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string Deal()
    {
        string Card = "";
        int cards = cardRandomizer.Next(1, 14);
        switch (cards)
        {
            case 1: Card = "Two"; total += 2;
                break;
            case 2: Card = "Three"; total += 3;
                break;
            case 3: Card = "Four"; total += 4;
                break;
            case 4: Card = "Five"; total += 5;
                break;
            case 5: Card = "Six"; total += 6;
                break;
            case 6: Card = "Seven"; total += 7;
                break;
            case 7: Card = "Eight"; total += 8;
                break;
            case 8: Card = "Nine"; total += 9;
                break;
            case 9: Card = "Ten"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 10: Card = "Jack"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 11: Card = "Queen"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 12: Card = "King"; total += 10;
                break;
            case 13: Card = "Ace"; total += 11;
                break;
            default: Card = "2"; total += 2;
                break;
        }
        return Card;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Start();
    }

    static void Hit()
    {
        count += 1;
        playerCards[count] = Deal();
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou were dealed a(n) " + playerCards[count] + ".\nYour new total is " + total + ".");
        if (total.Equals(21))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou got Blackjack! The dealer's total was " + dealerTotal + ".\nWould you like to play again?");
            PlayAgain();
        }
        else if (total > 21)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou busted, therefore you lost. Sorry. The dealer's total was " + dealerTotal + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
            PlayAgain();
        }
        else if (total < 21)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to hit or stay?");
                hitOrStay = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            } while (!hitOrStay.Equals("hit") && !hitOrStay.Equals("stay"));
            Game();
        }
    }

    static void PlayAgain()
    {
        string playAgain = "";
        do
        {
            playAgain = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        } while (!playAgain.Equals("y") && !playAgain.Equals("n"));
        if (playAgain.Equals("y"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to restart the game!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            dealerTotal = 0;
            count = 1;
            total = 0;
            Start();
        }
        else if (playAgain.Equals("n"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to close Blackjack.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wrap it within a `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why getting null value from console in c# for readLine() after using read()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781109/why-getting-null-value-from-console-in-c-sharp-for-readline-after-using-read)

Comment: @wudzik: Nothing to do with the linked question; the OP isn't calling `Read`.

Answer (score 8):

You are using `Console.ReadLine()` in a Windows Forms application. There is no console! `Console.ReadLine()` will always return `null` (immediately, without waiting for input). That's why you're seeing this issue.

I suspect that you need to create a new project, making sure you choose "Console Application" instead of "Windows Forms Application," and add your code to this application instead.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` acts upon the process' input stream. "Console" is a bit of a misnomer - you will be to able to read from it in WinForms if another processes pipes data in, for example. The distinction is important, despite you being spot on in this context.

Comment: Yes, @Gusdor, but there's nothing wired up to the console input in a WinForms app. [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `null` "if no more lines are available." In a WinForms app, this is always the case by default. Given the code posted, I doubt that the OP is rewiring standard input/output.

Comment: I agree. I'm not contradicting you, just adding flavour :)

Answer (score 2):

You may like to break this line into two parts:

```
hitOrStay = Console.ReadLine();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hitOrStay))
    hitOrStay = hitOrStay.ToLower();
```

Comment: While you'll fix the bug, you've missed the fundamental problem with what the OP is doing: `Console.ReadLine()` isn't going to work from a Windows Form.

Comment: @DanPuzey, what you have mentioned is absolutely right! I really missed the fact that this is a Windows Form Application. Thanks for acknowledging the fact and letting me know...silly me! :)